# PyQt4 not working on Spyder 3

Tags: python, pyqt4, spyder

I am trying to run a script with PyQt4 but Spyder gives an `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt4'` although it is installed. What am I doing wrong? I found a few threads in the net on this but I couldn't resolve the Problem.

Thanks in advance

Edit:

This is how I import it:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
```

and this is where I got Spyder 3 (with Anaconda):

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python

Comment: How have you installed it? 
and you could show how you import PyQt4

Comment: Did you pay for PyQt4?

Comment: @jmh No, why would I do that? Do I have to pay for PyQt4 to be able to use it in spyder?

Comment: i can't download it without having an account on the Anaconda Cloud. The area of cloud i need access to is not free. I guess i'm looking in wrong place.  Thanks.

Comment: Try here: https://www.anaconda.com/download/

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You probably installed PyQt4 in a different Python version or conda environment than the one Spyder is using. So you need to verify that this code `import sys; sys.executable()` returns the same result in a system terminal (cmd.exe, bash, Terminal.app) and inside Spyder.

Comment: Sorry, the code is `import sys; sys.executable`